# Magento2: what is the difference between container and list text?

Tags: magento2

The layout block `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText"` loops through all its child blocks same as the container. Based on what I see, they have the same purpose. Can you tell me what are the differences between the two and which one is best to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In block text list return all of its child and you can add any number of block inside it.

While a `container` can have `htmlTag` and `htmlClass` attributes on which you can define tag name and html class to that tag.

And it will generate a Dom element with specified tag and class attribute and will inject all its child block into that Dom.

> Using container you can define page layout without any template, you
>   just need to write your XML layout with containers.
>
> While you need to create many templates for each block to define
>   layout design.

Answer (score 0):

### Container

Outputs an HTML element and optional class attribute

### ListText Block

Does not output an HTML element, but has the benefit of allowing data set via XML by use of `<arguments>`

---

If you need an actual HTML element wrapper, use a `<container>`.  If you do not want an element or need to send data, use a "ListText" `<block>`.